# Tycho - "Unsatisfied constraint" on an Import-Package

Tags: maven, osgi, tycho

I'm just starting out with Tycho, and I'm stumped at an early stage.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, so just in case, here's what I'm expecting: I define my bundle's needs in OSGi style (i.e. in `MANIFEST.MF` via `Import-Package`), and Tycho somehow uses that info on the fly instead of me needing to redefine it all in Maven style (i.e. I don't have to put dependencies in pom.xml).

So, I made a simple Maven project, in Eclipse with the m2eclipse plugin, m2eclipse-tycho add on, and PDE plugin, and put the following Tycho stuff in the pom:

```
<properties>
    <tycho-version>0.15.0</tycho-version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Struggled through some wacky configuration errors, and finally got an essentially empty project (i.e. no source code) that gave no errors or warnings in Eclipse.  Then I copied my source code from another project in, and (as expected) got a bunch of compiler errors due to missing dependencies.  The first one was AbstractChannel from org.jboss.netty.channel.  I use version 3.5.1.Final of Netty, so I edited my MANIFEST.MF to include:

```
Import-Package: org.jboss.netty.channel;version="[3.5.1,4)"
```

I was then expecting Tycho to somehow magically figure out that I need Netty, and therefore act as if I had inserted something like the following into my Maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Instead, all that happened was I got one extra error in Eclipse, saying:

```
Unsatisfied constraint: 'Import-Package: org.jboss.netty.channel;version="[3.5.1,4.0.0)"
```

I don't know where to go from here.  Do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of what Tycho is supposed to do? Or is there something else that I have to set up in order for it to be able to do the "magical" translation from a `Import-Package` entry in `MANIFEST.MF` to a `<dependency>` pom.xml entry? Or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, there are some more hurdles to take.

In short, you will need to supply Tycho with a repository from which it can retrieve the dependencies.

In a bit more detail:

- you need to set up your target platform, and pass it to Tycho. I guess you've already set up your target platform in some way, otherwise Eclipse would complain too about not finding Netty.
- Make sure you share your target platform in your workspace, so Tycho can access it too.
- Tell Tycho to use that target platform like [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files)
- Tycho compatible target platforms *only* support p2 layouts, so no plain directories. I'm unsure what is the best way to make a p2 repo like that, as I've asked a [while back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191659/what-is-the-way-to-add-a-bundle-jar-to-a-p2-based-eclipse-target-platform). No answer whatsoever, but I do explain there what (sort of) works for me.

Hope it helps, Frank

Comment: Thanks! Target platform was what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is pretty good already, but there is a small but essential piece missing: Unlike in Maven, there is **no canonical default repository** (like "central") in Tycho. You need to configure where Tycho shall search for resolving the OSGi dependencies.

This search scope is called "[target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Glossary#Target_Platform)" in Tycho. There are [different ways so include artifacts in the target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform); the easiest one is to configure the p2 repository that contain your dependencies in the POM with an additional `<layout>p2</layout>` attribute (assuming you know a p2 repository containing the dependencies.)